# Wordpress store widget id's in an array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to store widget id's from a specific sidebar in an array. But I can't seem to get the first part done.

I have the following array:

```
$results = get_option('sidebars_widgets');
print_r($results); /* Gives me the following array */

Array
(
    [orphaned_widgets_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => search-2
            [1] => recent-posts-2
            [2] => recent-comments-2
            [3] => archives-2
            [4] => categories-2
            [5] => meta-2
        )

    [sidebar-footer] => Array
        (
        )

    [wp_inactive_widgets] => Array
        (
        )

    [sidebar-main] => Array
        (
        )

    [Shortcodes] => Array
        (
            [0] => pages-2
            [1] => widget-id
            [2] => another-id
            [3] => yet-another
        )

    [array_version] => 3
)
```

Then, I want all of the `Shortcodes` widget id's in array. Like doing:

```
$shortcode_widget_id = array();
foreach { code here to put the 4 id's in the $shortcode_widget_id array }
```

But how do I get the list of only the Shortcode id's, not the other ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$shortcode_array = $presentarray['Shortcodes'];
$shorcode_keys = array_keys( $shortcode_array);
print_r($shorcode_keys );
```

is this you are after ?

Comment: So, if the array was made by this $results = get_option('sidebars_widgets'); I should use $results['Shortcodes']; and so on? Because that gives me Array ( [0] => 0 )